# Sonar Failure because of org.sonar.plugins.surefire.api.SurefireUtils.getReportsDirectory(Lorg/sonar/api/resources/Project;)Ljava/io/File;

Tags: grails, groovy, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have couple of groovy/ grails projects and i am using sonar-runner to analyze them. They worked perfectly until today I started receiving this error :

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: org.sonar.plugins.surefire.api.SurefireUtils.getReportsDirectory(Lorg/sonar/api/resources/Project;)Ljava/io/File;
```

Not sure whats this, if somebody has experience this error before pls let me know

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem. The sonar-surefire-plugin-1.5.jar in your sonar/extensions.plugins/ directory I believe is the problem. I upgraded that to the 3.3.2 version from the maven repository; http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar.plugins/sonar-surefire-plugin, then restarted sonar and everything worked.  I am running the sonar-groovy-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT from cloud bees but I had the problem with their jar as well.

Comment: One additional note. I update several other plugins through sonar and it overwrote the surefire plugin with version 1.5 again. Quite a hassle.

Comment: Have you tried to use surefire 3.3.2 with the existing Groovy plugin version 0.6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I had the same problem after installin of sonar 3.7.3 (the latest) Before it  I have used sonar 3.5.X and all were OK. As possible solution: install previous version (3.6.X)

Comment: The thing is that initially had 3.7.2 and it worked perfectly fine and suddenly is choking a5t 09:45:31.447 INFO  - Sensor Groovy SurefireSensor...

Comment: I see they released one more upgrade 3.7.3

Comment: Hi! Today I have downloaded sonar-groovy-plugin-1.0 [see](http://repository-sonarplugins.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/sonar-groovy-plugin/1.0-SNAPSHOT/) and and installed it to sonar plugin folder <sonar_home>/extensions/plugins instead of existing (version 0.6). Now is ok

Comment: Sorry, It did not resolve my problem. I have project (based on maven) which contain java and groovy code. Groovy part is analize ok now. But project in common failed with the same problem as you.

Comment: @PeterSmith, why Groovy 1.0 is not in plugin updates or at plugin section ? According to SonarQube the latest version is 0.6!

Answer (score 0):

There's a compatibility issue between Java Plugins 1.5 and Groovy 0.6 (and also Flex 1.2). Related JIRA tickets: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-3178 and http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-3259. Compatibility matrix updated: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+version+matrix

Comment: I started over. Installed sonar 3.7.4, backed out from the EchoSystem 1.5 to 1.4, then installed the groovy .6 plugin and now it all works, completely.  Had to use sonar runner though. Had to also run the test from my project; grails test-app -coverage -xml. Once I pointed to the right place with sonar-runner, it had the unit test and full coverage information. I'm using sonar.surefire.reportsPath which I think is required from sonar 3.4 on.